# Spring Stomp @SubscribeMapping("/user/...") with User Destination doesn't work

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, spring-4, spring-websocket

I need to react on a user destination subscription.

### Example:

A user subscribes to `/user/messages`, because he wants to receive all incoming messages. Now I'd like to look up any messages for this user, which were created while he was offline, and then send them to that user.

### Working code:

Client code:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/messages', function(msg){
    alert(msg.body);
});
```

Server code:

```
template.convertAndSendToUser(p.getName(), "/messages", "message content");
```

### What I need:

It seems like it's not possible to catch an user destination subscription on server side, i.e.:

```
@SubscribeMapping("/user/messages")
public void test(Principal p) { 
    sendMessagesThatWereReceivedWhileUserWasOffline();
}
```

### What I tried:

```
@SubscribeMapping("/messages")
public void test(Principal p) { ... }
```

This works, if the client subscribes to `/app/messages`, **but it won't get called for** `/user/messages`.

### My Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/stomp").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
        return true;
    }

    // all other methods left empty
}
```

Using Spring 4.1.

---

I can't imagine that this isn't possible. What have I missed / done wrong?

Thank you `:)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Define the user prefix also as an application prefix, and you'll then be able to map the subscription in your controller. Configuration:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app", "/user");
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
    registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
}
```

Controller:

```
@SubscribeMapping("/messages")
public void test(Principal p) { 
    sendMessagesThatWereReceivedWhileUserWasOffline();
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Does this config "destroy" anything or change default behavior? I just wonder why this isn't the default setting

Comment: this configuration doesn't break anything, messages starting with /user will be delivered to both the user destination handler and your controllers

Comment: Is there also a solution without using Principal?

Comment: Pepster, you might ask in a separate question. You could use @Headers to get data from the headers of the message.. but this might be not what you wanted to ask.

Comment: Great answer thanks, however I am getting the following error? Any Suggestions? org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.MissingSessionUserException: No "user" header in message

Comment: Hi @SergiAlmar, I'm implementing Post and Comment module, how many subscriptions channel should I create e.g. addPost, updatePost, addComment, updateComment. Should I create individual subscription channel for all of them? This is not per user, visible for all users.